# How can I uninstall WinPython?

Tags: python

I have WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4

I'd like to uninstall all of it but I'm not sure how.
Is there an uninstaller I can run? Or do I have to go into the WinPython control panel, 
uninstall individual packages and then delete everything?

Answer (score 17):

WinPython is a portable application, so it is sufficient to just delete the folder where you installed it to.

However, in the WinPython control panel, one can register WinPython (`Advanced - Register Distribution`). If you have done this, you should unregister WinPython before deleting the folder by selecting `Advanced - Unregister Distribution` in the control panel. This is also described on the [WinPython Website (at the bottom)](https://winpython.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, there is not an uninstaller, as it only copies files to a destination directory. However, you can check if it does exist at the folder (it would say sth as WinPython...uninstaller.exe. If it does not, just take a look at the Windows control panel (there won't be anything probably, but let's try), or directly uninstall individual packages from Winpython and then delete all.